# time.clock is not accurate when calling parallel in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, time

I have a code looking like this:

```
tic = time.clock()  
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
diff_ev_result_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(processInput)(i) for i in range(len(i_j_list)))

for i,val in enumerate(i_j_list):
    training_result_x_dict[val[0]][val[1]]=diff_ev_result_list[i]

toc = time.clock()  
print "time spent is "+str(toc-tic)+"s"
```

The output is

```
time spent is 0.4s
```

However, the time spent is definitely much longer than that. Parallel comes from joblib. Do I miss anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. We need to use time.time()  instead of time.clock()